# mysql insert statements with '(' fail

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a file with more than 86000 insert statements . some of the insert statements are having `'(', ',', '\'` type of data in column data. Mysql is throwing an error and does not recognize the data as column data.

Is there any setting in MySQL like `set define off` in oracle ?

error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'guntur 
district, ap','08644 - 285237','chiluvuru','guntur','and pradesh'); inser' at line 1


 | Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
 | bank_name    | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
 | ifsc_code    | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | micr_code    | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
 | branch_name  | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
 | address      | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | phone_number | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | city         | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
 | district     | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | state        | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 +--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you share at least some of your exact sql statements? And also your table structure?

Comment: [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) is your friend.

Comment: insert into ifsc_codes(bank_name,ifsc_code,micr_code,branch_name,address,phone_number,city,district,state) values ('bank of baroda','barb0extchr','non micr','new osmangunj br., hyderabad, a.p.','new osmangunj, hyderabad, andhra pradesh - 500 012','040 - 23465134','hyderabad','hyderabad urban ','andhra pradesh');

Answer (score 0):

When I try to add `'\'`, `')'`, `'('`, `','` in my table, I am able to insert it..

Below is how I created table
`create table mytab4 (myChar char)` and `create table mytab4 (myChar varchar(20))` both ways..

Could you please provide your structure of table and query trying to execute...

Table structure can be seen by executing query `Describe myTable`

Good Luck...

Comment: Thanks.. i found the problem.. problem with chr(10) and chr(13) characters in oracle databas. when i exported this data from oracle to mysql. Mysql is throwing error. Thanks all

Comment: Why this row is throwing error..`code`insert into ifsc_codes(bank_name,ifsc_code,micr_code,branch_name,address,phone_number,city,district,state) values ('indian overseas bank','ioba0000415','141020009','threeke','opp. godawari motors;threeke-ferozepur road;ayali chowk;threeke;142021','p suresh kumar, senior manager, indian overseas bank, funds department, central office,','threeke','ludhiana','punjab');`code`

Comment: error is  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that                                                                              corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14202                                                                             1','p suresh kumar, senior manager, indian overseas bank, funds department,' at                                                                              line 1

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
shell> mysqlimport --fields-enclosed-by="'" db_name textfile1.sql
```

Check out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html

If all your fields are enclosed by a single quote and your single quotes within are escaped out (eg. values ('you're', 'no you\'re'));.

There is also an
    --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=string option too

Answer (score -1):

If you want to insert a `'\'` char, you should use `'\\'` else it consider the `\'` as an escape char and the query fail with the syntax error

Comment: Of course. I just noted that often I find this type of error, so I supposed it can be something similar